# Computing smallest singular value of a matrix with explicit error control?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

[Also posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/464433/]

Many good algorithms are out there computing truncated SVD: https://mathoverflow.net/q/161252.

I am trying to implement some codes to find the smallest singular value of a big matrix $A$. ARPACK can do that via eigenvalues of $M = A^\ast A,$ using Arnoldi methods. However, the "naive" version converges extremely slow when eigenvalues are clustered together.

The shift-and-invert technique speed up convergence a lot. Suppose that we know $\mu>0$ is very close to $\sigma_\text{min}>\mu,$ the smallest singular value of $M.$ Then we can consider $(M-\mu I)^{-1}$ which "pulls" clusters of eigenvalues apart.

The issue is that - this technique requires a **lower bound** on $\sigma_\text{min},$ which I do not know any algorithm to calculate. And frankly, obtaining a lower bound seems a very necessary thing on its own - otherwise how can we be sure that the Arnoldi iterates are accurate? **Does anybody know such an algorithm?**

By the way, the stopping criterion of ARPACK is designed so that we can *"expect"*
$$
|\lambda_c - \lambda_a| \leq \epsilon |\lambda_c|
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the error tolerance parameter, $\lambda_c$ the computed eigenvalue, and $\lambda_a$ the closest actual eigenvalue. This does not help my question because

1. Guaranteeing this stopping criterion makes the algorithm extremely slow, even with huge $\epsilon$ like $0.5.$ Conceptually the inequality above is way stronger than what I need.
2. For such huge epsilon, the inequality does **not** really hold in general in practice when the algorithm halts.

Comment: Why do you need $\mu>0$? As far as I know you can also use $\mu=0$ or $\mu<0$ in shift-and-invert Arnoldi.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You are right. But here, we already know a priori that all eigenvalues are non-negative, so $\mu<0$ does not help at all.

Comment: @MaJoad Then don't you know a lower bound of $\sigma_{\min}$, namely $0$?

Comment: @lightxbulb Yes, but this bound might not be good enough to reasonably speed up convergence!

Comment: Do you know anything about the structure or distribution of $A$ *a priori*? There may be some heuristics from tail estimates in random matrix theory that could provide decent first guesses.

Comment: @whpowell96 In my case, this is extremely simple - I am evaluating the smallest singular value of $A-\lambda I$ for a collection of $\lambda.$